# Fetch only albums in a PHCollectionList

Tags: ios, ios8, photokit, phasset, phfetchoptions

A `PHCollectionList` is a folder that could contain any number of albums and/or folders. I am currently fetching the collections within the list via `PHCollection.fetchCollectionsInCollectionList(list, options: nil)`.

This could return objects of type `PHAssetCollection` or `PHCollectionList`. I am only interested in knowing of the `PHAssetCollection`s in that list. The docs state you can apply a filter predicate using the fetch options in order to return a subset of the data, but I don't see how I would use that in order to only get albums. How do you use `PHFetchOptions` in order to return only `PHAssetCollection`s in a given `PHCollectionList`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
    [PHCollectionList fetchCollectionListsWithType:<filterType> subtype:nil optionsnil]
```

Where your `<ftilerType>` could be anything from `PHCollectionListType`:

- **PHCollectionListTypeMomentList** - Moments created by iPhone (essentially all photos grouped into Year and Collections)
- **PHCollectionListTypeFolder** - user created Albums (folders)
- **PHCollectionListTypeSmartFolder** - Smart folders created by the iPhone automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can use predicate to specify the album's name and use it to fetch specific Album from the collectionList.

```
PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
fetchOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title = %@", ABC];

PHFetchResult *collectionsFetchResult = [PHCollection fetchCollectionsInCollectionList:self.collectionList options:fetchOptions];

PHAssetCollection *ABCAlbum = collectionsResult.firstObject;
  NSLog(@"ABC album details: %@", ABCAlbum);
```

Or you can put nil in options and get all of the AssetCollections in the List.

```
    PHFetchResult *collectionsFR = [PHCollection fetchCollectionsInCollectionList:list options:nil];
      if ( collectionsFR.count > 0) {
        for ( PHAssetCollection *collection in collectionsFR) {
          // do something with each album
          NSLog(@"collection is %@", collection);
        }
      }
```